# how to get a particular location on google maps with markers from a angular dropdown list

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to do some location search on google maps,its like i am having a angular multi-select drop-down where i am having several locations, if i select a single  location or more ,i have to show them on maps using markers,and how to get our current location any suggestions on how to do it please.

**Dropdown code**

```
<div class="m-r" 
     ng-dropdown-multiselect="" 
     options="locations"  
     selected-model="search.locations" 
     extra-settings="multiSelectSettingsFunction" 
     translation-texts ="locationsTexts"  
     settings="selectSettings">
</div>
```

**Google maps code**

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" refresh="true" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true" data-tap-disabled="true">
    <ui-gmap-window show="map.window.show" coords="map.window.model" options="map.window.options" closeClick="map.window.closeClick()">
        <div style="color: black" background-color="#337ab7">
            {{map.window.title}}
            {{map.window.venue}}
        </div>
    </ui-gmap-window>
    <ui-gmap-markers idkey="marker.id" models="map.markers" coords="'self'" doCluster="false" fit="'true'" icon="'icon'" events="map.markersEvents " options="'options'"></ui-gmap-markers>

</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

**controller.js**

```
app.controller("MainController", [ '$anchorScroll', '$scope', '$http', '$modal', '$log', '$timeout', '$location', '$rootScope', '$window','$mdSidenav' , function ($anchorScroll, $scope, $http, $modal, $log, $timeout, $location, $rootScope, $window,$mdSidenav) {
  $scope.searchBack = window.sessionStorage.searchBack;
  $scope.search = {
      pax: '',
      data: '',         
      locations : [],
      distance  : []
  }

  $scope.$watch('search.locations', function(newVal, oldVal){
      //console.log(newVal);
      //$scope.setSearch();
  }, true);

  $scope.locationsTexts = {
      buttonDefaultText: 'Locations',
      dynamicButtonTextSuffix: 'Locations',
  }

  $scope.multiSelectSettings = {
        displayProp: 'locations',
        idProp: 'locations',
        scrollableHeight: '256px',
        scrollable: true,
        enableSearch: true,
        buttonDefaultText: 'asd',
        dynamicButtonTextSuffix: 'Locations',
        //showCheckAll: false, 
   };

$scope.locations = [                  
  {id: 1, label: "kothapet"}, 
  {id: 2, label: "Dsnr"}, 
  {id: 3, label: "Malakpet"},
  {id: 4, label: "Chadarghat"}, 
  {id: 5, label: "Koti"}, 
  {id: 6, label: "abids"}

  ];
```

**Maps Controller**

```
app.controller('MapController2', function($scope, $rootScope, $http) {
        var data = {};

        data.map = {
            zoom: 16,
            center: {
              latitude: 17.399,
              longitude: 78.52
            },
            markers: [
                {
                    id: 1,

                    latitude: 17.3762,
                    longitude: 78.5461,
                    title: 'Location:Nagole',
                    venue:'Venue: Ng builders'
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    latitude: 17.3710,
                    longitude: 78.5410,
                    title: 'Location:Kothapet',
                    venue:'Venue: A Builders'
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    latitude: 17.3688,
                    longitude: 78.5247,
                    title: 'Location:Dilsukhnagar',
                    venue:'Venue: B Builders'
                },
                {
                    id: 4,
                    latitude: 17.3667,
                    longitude: 78.500,
                    title: 'Location:Malakpet',
                    venue:'Venue: C Builders'
                }],
            markersEvents: {
                click: function(marker, eventName, model, arguments) {
                    console.log('Marker was clicked (' + marker + ', ' + eventName);//+', '+mydump(model, 0)+', '+mydump(arguments)+')');
                    $scope.map.window.model = model;
                    $scope.map.window.model = model;
                    $scope.map.window.title = model.title;
                    $scope.map.window.venue = model.venue;
                    $scope.map.window.show = true;
                }
            },
            window: {
                marker: {},
                show: false,
                closeClick: function() {
                    this.show = false;
                },
                options: {}, // define when map is ready
                title: ''

            }
        };

        //$scope.window = false;

        $scope.onMarkerClicked = function (m) {
            //this.windowOptions = !this.windowOptions;
            console.log('Marker was clicked');
            console.log(m);
        };

        $scope.closeClick = function () {
            this.window = false;
        };

        $scope.map = data.map;





    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) To resolve *location by address name* utilize [Google Maps Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro), for example:

```
var resolveAddress = function(address) {
        var deffered = $q.defer();
        $http({
                url: 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + address + '&sensor=false',
                method: 'GET'
            }).
            success(function(data) {
                deffered.resolve(data);
            }).
            error(function(error) {
                deffered.reject();
            });
        return deffered.promise;
    };
```

2) For [`angularjs-dropdown-multiselect` component](http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/#/) you could utilize `events` to add events what the directive fires, for example `onItemSelect` which triggers once the item is selected:

```
<div class="m-r"
     ng-dropdown-multiselect=""
     options="locations"
     selected-model="search.locations"
     translation-texts="locationsTexts"
     settings="selectSettings"
     events="{ onItemSelect: showItemOnMap }">
</div>


$scope.showItemOnMap = function(item) {
   //...
};
```

The following demo demonstrates how to display markers on map from items selected in `angularjs-dropdown-multiselect` control

[**Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/bfW86DnlmR2gFCvHscwQ?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for help. Sorry for being late. I was trying to modify your code ,where if i deselect a particular location the marker should disappear. Can u help me with the functionality please ?